# Can I reuse the threads for all the iterations of the for loop here?

Tags: java, multithreading

From http://www.siddhartha.ac.in/downloads/JP_Lab_Record2.pdf.

> Write Java Program that implements a multithread application that has
>   three threads. First thread generates Random integer for every second
>   and if the value is even, second thread computes the square of number
>   and prints. If the value is odd, the third thread will print the value
>   of cube of number.
>
> ```
> import java.util.*;
> class even implements Runnable
> {
>     public int x;
>     public even(int x)
>     {
>         this.x = x;
>     }
>     public void run()
>     {
>         System.out.println("New Thread "+ x +" is EVEN and Square of " + x + " is: " + x * x);
>     }
> }
> class odd implements Runnable
> {
>     public int x;
>     public odd(int x)
>     {
>         this.x = x;
>     }
>     public void run()
>     {
>         System.out.println("New Thread "+ x +" is ODD and Cube of " + x + " is: " + x * x * x);
>     }
> }
> class A extends Thread
> {
>     public void run()
>     {
>         int num = 0;
>         Random r = new Random();
>         try
>             {
>                 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
>                     {
>                         num = r.nextInt(100);
>                         System.out.println("Main Thread and Generated Number is " + num);
>                         if (num % 2 == 0)
>                             {
>                               Thread t1 = new Thread(new even(num));
>               t1.start();
>                             } else {
>                             Thread t2 = new Thread(new odd(num));
>                             t2.start();
>           }
>                         Thread.sleep(1000);
>           System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
>                     }
>             }
>         catch (Exception ex)
>             {
>                 System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
>             }
>     }
> }
> public class JavaProgram5
> {
>     public static void main(String[] args)
>     {
>         A a = new A();
>         a.start();
>     }
> }
> ```

In the `main` method, for each iteration of the for loop, two new threads are created. Is it possible to reuse the two threads for all the iterations of the for loop?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you doing this with multiple threads? You are likely to encounter lots of synchronicity problems. Why not just have the one thread print the values?

Comment: @FredK it sounds like an assignment designed to create synchronization issues

Comment: @John It was an assignment, but I am thinking beyond the assignment.

Comment: It is convention to start class names with upper-case letters.

Comment: What is the subject of the lesson? Is it producers and consumers for example? Because that is really what you should be doing here.

Comment: @Mad I am not sure how to view the problem as producer-consumer one. Is the main thread   the producer, and the other two threads consumers?

Comment: You should be starting three threads in `main`: Thread A runs forever, generating your numbers after a one second sleep cycle and placing them into a queue and notifying all waiting threads. Thread Even sleeps until woken. It peeks at the items in the queue. If the top item is even, it pops it and processes it. Otherwise it leaves it alone and goes back to sleep until the next notification. Same for Thread Odd, but for odd numbers.

Comment: @Ben. Yes, one thread here is producing something which the others are required to consume. That's just the nature of the problem, even if the statement does not use those exact words.

Comment: Any situation where a thread or threads are constantly producing output and other threads are doing something with that output is likely to be a producer-consumer situation. Here the additional catch is that your consumers need to know whether to consume a value or leave it alone for the next consumer to check.

Comment: Would you like for me to write up a response?

Comment: @Mad Yes, that will be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can not restart a thread, see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start--

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once

However you might want to take a look into using a `ThreadPool`. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Answer (score 0):

Threads can not be reused in the way that you are thinking. What you are doing is actually starting a fresh thread every time you generate a number. At that point, you may as well not have a separate thread for the calculations at all.

The subtext of the question seems to be indicating that you have three threads always running. That makes your problem essentially a producer with two consumers situation. The only catch is that the consumers must act intelligently and only pick up the data that they need.

Your generator code is off on the right track, as is the processing code. The main change that needs to happen is that instead of starting a new thread, the producer should [`notify`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify--) (actually [`notifyAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll--)) the threads running `Even` and `Odd`.

Since we produce one item every second, you don't really need a proper queue. A single `Integer` object will be enough to hold the unconsumed number. If processing takes longer than one second even on relatively older architecture, you have other problems to worry about. The reason for using an `Integer` instead of an `int` is that you need to be able to signal to the waiting threads that the object has already been consumed: in this case returning `null` seems like a pretty easy way.

```
class Producer implements Runnable, IntConsumer
{
    private Integer buffer = null;

    public void run()
    {
        new Random().ints().forEach(this);
    }

    public void accept(int i)
    {
        synchronized(this) {
            this.buffer = i;
            this.notifyAll();
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000L);
        } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Producer interrupted!");
        }
    }

    public Integer peek()
    {
        return this.buffer;
    }

    public synchronized Integer get()
    {
        Integer i = peek();
        this.buffer = null;
        return i;
    }
}
```

Notice that the integer that is generated is placed in a field that can be accessed through `peek` and `get`. The generation code locks on the producer object, as does `get`, which clears the buffer. This ensures that only one entity can modify the value at a time.

Normally consumers and producers would communicate through a shared stack or queue object, or something similar. Synchronization is done by the queue as well, as in a [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html) or [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingDeque.html). In this simple case, the producer implements the queue functionality, so the consumers have to be aware of the producer.

The consumer threads have a lot of common functionality. They both have to wait for the producer's notification, acquire the lock, check if the next object is unconsumed and belongs to them, then consume it or keep waiting. Notice that the entire check-then-get operation should be atomic to avoid errors. All this can be easily encoded in a base class. This class will have abstract methods to check and process the numbers:

```
public abstract class Consumer implements Runnable
{
    private final Producer producer;

    public Consumer(Producer producer)
    {
        this.producer = producer;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while(true) {
            synchronized(this.producer) {
                Integer i = this.producer.peek();
                if(i != null && check(i)) {
                    this.producer.get();
                    process(i);
                }
                try {
                    this.producer.wait();
                } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Consumer interrupted!");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract boolean check(int i);

    public abstract void process(int i);
}
```

The concrete implementations check if the parity of the number inputs, and process the numbers that they are suited for. Notice that I made `check` and `process` accept `int` instead of `Integer` to emphasize that it is not their responsibility to check if the producer is empty.

```
public class Even extends Consumer
{
    public Even(Producer producer)
    {
        super(producer);
    }

    public boolean check(int i)
    {
        return (i % 2) == 0;
    }

    public void process(int i)
    {
        System.out.println("x=" + i + "; x^2=" + (i * i));
    }
}
```

```
public class Odd extends Consumer
{
    public Odd(Producer producer)
    {
        super(producer);
    }

    public boolean check(int i)
    {
        return (i % 2) != 0;
    }

    public void process(int i)
    {
        System.out.println("x=" + i + "; x^3=" + (i * i * i));
    }
}
```

Finally, the driver containing the `main` method that ties all this together:

```
public class Driver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Producer prod = new Producer();
        new Thread(new Even(prod)).start();
        new Thread(new Odd(prod)).start();
        new Thread(prod).start();
    }
}
```

If you have trouble with the main thread exiting early, force `main` to wait for the producer to finish (forever) with something like:

```
Thread t = new Thread(prod);
t.start();
t.join();
```

The code will produce output like the following, once every second until you press `Ctrl+C` (on Linux at least):

```
x=966307133; x^3=-1676528219
x=1271569805; x^3=-1481001707
x=456385150; x^2=-1701399036
x=-474801821; x^3=-813682373
x=-1046547765; x^3=927976307
x=-148577454; x^2=-185956796
x=-14905035; x^3=-1126539123
x=2071820769; x^3=-1426032223
x=1075272421; x^3=1952259101
x=-895041093; x^3=-978791741
x=-2054472224; x^2=3441664
...
```

Answer (score 0):

use a fixedThread pool.it reuses the threads

```
            import java.util.Random;
            import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
            import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
            import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


            public class MainClass {

                public static void main(String[] args){


                      A a = new A();
                        a.start();

                }

            }

            class A extends Thread
            {
                public void run()
                {

                    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
                    int num = 0;
                    Random r = new Random();
                    try
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                                {
                                    num = r.nextInt(100);
                                    System.out.println("Main Thread and Generated Number is " + num);
                                    if (num % 2 == 0)
                                        {
                                         executorService.submit(new even(num));

                                        } else {
                                             executorService.submit(new odd(num));

                      }
                                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                      System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
                                }
                        }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                        }
                 finally {
                    executorService.shutdown();
                }
                try {
                    executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
            }

            class even implements Runnable
            {
                public int x;
                public even(int x)
                {
                    this.x = x;
                }
                public void run()
                {
                    System.out.println("New Thread "+ x +" is EVEN and Square of " + x + " is: " + x * x);
                }
            }
            class odd implements Runnable
            {
                public int x;
                public odd(int x)
                {
                    this.x = x;
                }
                public void run()
                {
                    System.out.println("New Thread "+ x +" is ODD and 
               Cube of " + x + " is: " + x * x * x);
                }
            }
```